# Table cell (TD) dynamically sizing to width of longest word in column. What style causes this?

Tags: css, html, layout

Webkit inspector is unable to tell me why my table cells are not obeying the `width` style. I can get them to either stretch to fit the entire line (by setting `white-space: nowrap` or to stretch to fit the longest word, but I just want the cells to be some number of pixels wide.

Comment: Are you trying to do anything different that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, check this out:

[Fixed Table Cell Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185814/fixed-table-cell-width)

Now,

for fixed cell size (`<td>`) use:

```
<col width="50px"/>
```

before your

```
<tr>
```

Alternatively, use:

```
<table width = 100>
```

OR

```
<table style="width:100px">
```

To fix the table size.

The "break word" value for "word wrap" property in your css is useful in these cases:

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `table-layout: fixed;` to your table's CSS declaration.