# Editable div in table exceeds its percentage-width when content is very long

Tags: html, css, width, contenteditable

I'm using Chrome. I have a editable DIV inside a table, whose width is defined by percentage. Its CSS is as below:

```
div#editable {
    width:20%;
    white-space:nowrap;    
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid darkgrey;
}
```

When adding very long content into the DIV, its width begins to increase regardless of the CSS definition. Here is a demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/k5Erc/. You can try to input more content into the DIV and see its width growing.

However, if its width is defined by px or em, there is no such problem.

Could anyone tell me how to fix its width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wish for your text to wrap, so the width stays the same you need to get rid off `white-space:nowrap;` Otherwise add `table-layout:fixed;` to your table css

See the updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/k5Erc/1/

Comment: I need `white-space:nowrap` because I want to use `text-overflow:ellipsis;`. `table-layout:fixed` works, although I need to define column width in the way described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185814/fixed-table-cell-width). Thanks!