# fix the table td width

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to design like above table

I have implemented like this. Please check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/480/).

HTML:

```
<table border="0" id="cssTable">
    <tr>
        <td>eredgb</td>
        <td><a href="self">04-Milwaukee</a></td>
        <td>705</td>
        <td>sdfdfdfed</td>
        <td>298</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</td>
        <td><a href="self">04-Milwaukee</a></td>
        <td>705</td>
        <td>content2</td>
        <td>298</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</td>
        <td><a href="self">04-Milwaukee edh walkohnykuohbnbd</a></td>
        <td>705</td>
        <td>content1</td>
        <td>298</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#cssTable{
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

How can I make this like the screenshot above? I need to provide equal spacing and some fixed width for each table `td` content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Take a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/483/).

You can use the css selector `:nth-child()`to target a specific column.

```
#cssTable td {
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#cssTable td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: am just using this when i increasing the width to 500px the text is not come to up. it stays there only. what is the use of width ?http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/487/

Comment: It depends on the overall width of the table, if you want it to be _exactly_ 500px, set the min-width as well - http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/488/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to space each td differently you can use the nth-child selector:

```
#cssTable{margin-left:20px;}  
#cssTable tr td:nth-child(1){width: 100px; padding-right: 10px;}
#cssTable tr td:nth-child(2){width: 300px; padding-right: 10px;}
#cssTable tr td:nth-child(3){width: 50px; padding-right: 10px;}
#cssTable tr td:nth-child(4){width: 100px; padding-right: 10px;}
#cssTable tr td:nth-child(5){width: 50px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mLpH9/2/

If your table gets bigger you can of course set the padding-right for all columns and set it for last-child to 0.

Answer (score 0):

try this

set css to the table td tag.

```
table td {
    width: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

or create class and set the name  .

```
<td class="special_column">...</td>
```

Comment: i want to text to be wrap for longer length not to be hidden state.

Answer (score 0):

[Like this ?](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/485/) (updated inspired by @Grey 's code)

```
#cssTable td {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

#cssTable a {
    color:red;
}

#cssTable td:nth-child(1) {
    width:20px;
}
#cssTable td:nth-child(2) {
    width:200px;
}
#cssTable td:nth-child(3),#cssTable td:nth-child(5) {
    width:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#cssTable td:nth-child(4) {
    width:20px;
}
```

You need to insert a fix width for every td of one line. The others just copy the ones who have width. You can add a Class to each cell in function of its column.
You can too insert width in % so your display is going to increse if you have big resolution.

Comment: this will not simlar too like above design. i need design like which i was pasted the layout in my question

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<colgroup>` and `<col>`. You won't need to give every `<td>` a separate class this way.

```
<table border="0" id="cssTable">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="100px" />
        <col width="100px" />
        <col width="50px" />
        <col width="75px" />
        <col width="50px" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        ...
```

Also check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/482/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the table never forces td to use specified width until you use

`table { table-layout: fixed; }`

and make a first row of table with

`td { height: 0; }`

and specify width for every td in this row.

By standard you can also use <col> but in some browsers this does not work, td works everywhere.

This kind of questions is asked many times in different places, [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185814/fixed-table-cell-width)

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your css

```
#cssTable td
{
 padding:0 20px;
}
```

It will add padding to left and right.
http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/484/