# how to get fixed table columns width in html table with a php loop

Tags: php, html

This is my code to get data from a database to a html table. but column size expand with the size of the details. i need to get a fixed size columns.  please help me to get fixed size columns.

```
<?php 
ini_set ('display_errors',0);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    require_once 'issue_tracker_connection.php';
    mysql_select_db('issue_tracker');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM issue_tracker";
    $records = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<html>

<head>
<style>

table th, td{
    table-layout:fixed;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    align:center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
echo '<table >';
$columns = array();
$resultset = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
    if (empty($columns)) {
        $columns = array_keys($row);
        echo '<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $columns).'</th></tr>';
    }
    $resultset[] = $row;
    echo '<tr><td >'.implode('</td><td>', $row).'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding width on `table` , also on `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
echo '<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">';
$columns = array();
$resultset = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
    if (empty($columns)) {
        $columns = array_keys($row);
        echo '<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $columns).'</th></tr>';
    }
    $resultset[] = $row;
    echo '<tr><td >'.implode('</td><td>', $row).'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: Check this : if (empty($columns)) {
        $columns = array_keys($row);
       $totlength = count($row);
      $thwidth = ceil(100/$totlength);
      $stringData = '</th><th width = '.$thwidth.'%>';
        echo '<tr><th>'.implode(stringData, $columns).'</th></tr>';
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can also set size of  tag...
Try it now...

```
<tr>
<td width="50%">Your Code Here</td>
<td width="50%">Your Code Here</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: my table is updating by adding new columns. hence i need width size as 20px.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<table class="fixed">
    <col width="20px" />
    <col width="30px" />
    <col width="40px" />
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

and CSS:

```
table.fixed { table-layout:fixed; }
table.fixed td { overflow: hidden; }
```

Check original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185874/4977402).