# <TD> cells are changing size when grids are populated

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm working on this page that, unfortunately, has its layout largely based on tables and I don't have the time nor the skills to do it properly (new to web dev / design).

I have 1 `TR` with 2 `TD`'s inside.

- Inside the first `TD` is a nested table which has 1 `TR` and 1 `TD` which contains an `ASP:DataGrid` control.
- The second `TD` also has a nested table, which contains 1 `TR`, 1 `TD`, and 2 `ASP:DataGrid` controls. These `ASP:DataGrid`'s are contained in  2x `<div style="OVERFLOW:auto;WIDTH:100%;HEIGHT:191px">` inside the `TD`.

When the user clicks the search button, the first grid in the first `TD` on the left of the screen is populated. This `TD` takes up about 3/4 of the `TR`. When they select a row, the grids on the right, in the second `TD`, are populated, but these expand and now both `TD`'s take up about 1/2 each.

I cannot figure out why their widths are changing.

Actual HTML/ASP looks like this:

```
<TR>
    <TD align="left" colSpan="5" height="242" valign="top" align="center">
        <TABLE class="clsBorderColor" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" height="100%">
            <TR>
                <TD valign="top" class="style2">
                    <asp:datagrid id="dgICDCodes" runat="server" bodyHeight="300px" CssClass="tblScroll" Width="100%" PageSize="12">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="clsGridHeaderText" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                                <HeaderTemplate>Select</HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate><asp:RadioButton ID="rbSelect" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbSelect_CheckedChanged" ondatabinding="rbSelect_DataBinding" /></ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="clsGridHeaderText" Width="10%"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="10%"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:datagrid>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </TD>

    <TD colspan="3" valign="top" align="center">
        <TABLE class="clsBorderColor" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="100%">
            <TR>
                <TD>Additional Code For Tier
                    <DIV style="OVERFLOW:auto;WIDTH:100%;HEIGHT:191px">
                        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgICDCodes_AdditionalTier" runat="server" bodyHeight="400px" CssClass="tblScroll" Width="100%">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="clsGridHeaderText" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>Select</HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Checkbox ID="chkTSelect" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" ondatabinding="chkSelect_DataBinding" /></ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="clsGridHeaderText" Width="10%"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="10%"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:DataGrid>
                    </DIV>
                    <BR />Additional Code For Compliance
                    <DIV style="OVERFLOW:auto;WIDTH:100%;HEIGHT:191px">
                        <asp:datagrid id="dgICDCodes_AdditionalCompliance" runat="server" bodyHeight="400px" CssClass="tblScroll" Width="100%">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="clsGridHeaderText" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>Select</HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Checkbox ID="chkPSelect" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" ondatabinding="chkSelect_DataBinding" /></ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="clsGridHeaderText" Width="10%"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="10%"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:datagrid>
                    </DIV>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

The two root-most `TD` elements are set to colspan 5 & 3, as I don't want them to be equal widths. Anything with a width property is set to 100%, thinking that it should take up the full width of the containing element.

For the CSS:

```
.style2
{
    width: 650px;
}

.clsBorderColor
{
    border-right: #0080c0 1px solid;
    border-top: #0080c0 1px solid;
    border-left: #0080c0 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #0080c0 1px solid;
}
```

`.tblScroll` is actually empty in the CSS file and `.clsGridHeaderText` just sets font colors and things like that.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: add a css property to your table:
`table-layout: fixed;`

Comment: Read [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185814/fixed-table-cell-width) answers to get your answer.

Comment: @VibhorDube How do defining column widths work like that when you have TD's that span across a row? Some rows just have 1 TD that spans 8 columns, some rows have 8 columns.

Comment: if you set the `width` of the first row of cells (possibly your <th> in your <thead>) that will set the width for the 'columns' and cells in rows below that have a colspan, will size accordingly. You can also use a CSS specific selector on attribute: `[colspan="2"] { width: ... } [colspan="3"] { width: ... }` if that works better for you