# html table columns of fixed width

Tags: html, css

i have a html table like:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center" border="0">
<tr>
    <td width="7%"></td>
    <td width="21%"></td>
    <td width="32%"></td>
    <td width="20%"></td>
    <td width="20%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this is working good, but some times if column no 5 has large content then column no 4 shrinks and width of these columns does not remains equal

Comment: can you show the exact problem in your code?

Comment: any demo fiddle/snippet??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed Table Cell Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185814/fixed-table-cell-width)

Comment: try using <div> tag inside the <td> tag with width:100%

Comment: [Fixed Table Cell Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185814/fixed-table-cell-width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 
.table{
    table-layout:fixed;} and .table tr td{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-align:center;} for applying width and text as per width

```css
.table{
table-layout:fixed;}
.table tr td{
word-wrap:break-word;
text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center" border="0" class="table">
<tr>
    <td width="7%">ew</td>
    <td width="21%">ewwe</td>
    <td width="32%">weew</td>
    <td width="20%">ewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewew</td>
    <td width="20%">eweweew</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are looking for is `word-break: break-all;` style on your `<td>`.

```css
.table-style td {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.td-break-word {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-style"  width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center" border="0">
<tr>
    <td width="7%">text</td>
    <td width="21%">text</td>
    <td width="32%">text</td>
    <td width="20%">text</td>
    <td width="20%" class="td-break-word">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to print a single big string. If there is a space, the words will be broken according to the width automatically. Use the below CSS to fix it.

```
 tr td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

PS: String will be broken into multiple lines. The row may look long.