# Force TD width, inside TR who's inside TBODY

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a html template where it has :

```
table
  thead
    tr
      th
      th
      th
  tbody
    tr
      td
      td
      td
```

My th, who contains titles of table, have properties: `width="180"` for the first one and the second one, and `width="360"` for the third.

I have long texts in the third td tag below tr, but it overflows a lot. How can I handle it, for having my column with a fixed width (360)? I already tried many things that I read from other topics, but nothing worked: `position: fixed, overflow: hidden` and etc, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed Table Cell Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185814/fixed-table-cell-width)

Comment: You shouldn't use the `width` attribute - it was deprecated in html4 and is now obsolete in html5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td (same for th as it is for td)

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Can you show your code? Also, what is your expected result? Why not to use `overflow`?